# Determine rdf mime-types in bash

Tags: bash, unix, rdf, rdf4j

I am writing a bash script, that needs to check the different mime-types of different files. The files should support rdf4j REST API (http://docs.rdf4j.org/rest-api/#_content_types).

Normally, using `file --mime-type <file>` provides the correct mime type. However, when running on a .ttl file, it returns wrong: 
`foo.ttl: text/plain` instead of `text/turtle`

Does it exist a better way to solve this, then checking every file-ending, for each file?

Comment: Edit file /etc/magic observe how this is done for other file types and add something for text/turtle

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alternative to `file`, for instance `mimetype`.

At least the following example file from the wikipedia entry on .ttl is recognized as `text/turtle`:

```
$ cat test.ttl
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/stuff/1.0/> .

<http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar>
  dc:title "RDF/XML Syntax Specification (Revised)" ;
  ex:editor [
    ex:fullname "Dave Beckett";
    ex:homePage <http://purl.org/net/dajobe/>
  ] .
$ mimetype test.ttl 
test.ttl: text/turtle
```

`mimetype` is provided by the package `perl-file-mimeinfo` in arch linux and by `libfile-mimeinfo-perl` on debian and ubuntu.

Comment: cheers. Your solution makes it pssoble to check mimetype for ttl. But still missing support for nq, trix, n3 etc.

Comment: You can add mime types manually by editing `/etc/mime.types` or creating your own `/usr/share/mime/text/yourfiletype.xml` (see `/usr/share/mime/text/turtle.xml` for an example). You might need to run `update-mime-database` afterwards.